Possibility on Migrating Old Huge Project into Jetpack Compose
So, I was developing this huge app back in 2020 or so, still using xmls and all of that, and then I'm out. Now, I want to continue working on that app, but I've seen things changed drastically with Jetpack Compose.
Is it possible to convert my project into Jetpack Compose so I can use the most updated SDK version and all of latest other libraries? Or can I still continue the old coding style with xml, while still using the latest version of SDK & libraries? (I remember people said that I can't though.)
Or should I just give up and re-code everything from scratch? 
(Sorry for grammars as English isn't my native language)

I'm not aware of a deadline up until that you would need to have migrated to Compose. The SDK should (yet) be fully compatible with XML layouts. That said the focus definitely lies on Compose, and some of the new requirements (e.g. the edge-to-edge enforcement in Android 15) might be difficult to properly implement without Compose.
Migrating to Compose should theoretically only affect your UI, but in reality you probably need to update some of the rest of your code as well, especially if your existing code doesn't conform to clean architecture, doesn't adhere to UDF and doesn't use Flows in your data layer and view models. Although that is good practice independent of the UI framework you use, setting up a Compose UI without it is quite inconvenient.
To directly answer your question: Yes, you can continue with your XML layouts although over time it might become more and more inconvenient to use compared to Compose. Migrating to Compose, on the other hand, requires you to familiarize yourself with the new Compose Framework and will result in a major refactoring of your code base.
Only you can decide if migrating is worth it in your current situation.
